# Socket Error::Address Already In Use

Tags: sockets

I am facing this problem of Binding to socket.
1st instance works properly i.e. 
socket() returns success and hence forth bind() and listen(), accept() and hence recv() - All fine till here.
2nd instance throw error while binding "Address already in use"

I went through all the post earlier on this and i dont see any specific solution provided on the same.

My code is as below :-

```
if((status = getaddrinfo(NULL,"8080",&hints,&servinfo))!=0){
        ALOGE("Socket:: getaddrinfo failed %s\n",strerror(errno));
        return NULL;
    }

    server_sockfd = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype, servinfo->ai_protocol);
    if(server_sockfd == -1) {
        ALOGE("Socket:: Scoket System Call failed %s\n",strerror(errno));
        return NULL;
    }

    if ((setsockopt(server_sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(int))) < 0)
    {
        ALOGE("Socket:: setsockopt failed %s\n",strerror(errno));
        return NULL;
    }

    ret = bind(server_sockfd, servinfo->ai_addr,servinfo->ai_addrlen);
    if(ret!=0) {
        ALOGE("Socket:: Error Binding on socket %s\n",strerror(errno));
        return NULL;
    }
```

This code runs on android platform.

I have properly closed each session before opening a new session as below :-

```
ret = shutdown(client_sockfd,0);
if(ret != 0)
    ALOGE("Socket:: Shutdown Called%s\n",strerror(errno));
```

I tried with close as well but it did not work.

Surprisingly the error does not disappear even when we try to open the socket after long time (as per TIME_WAIT logic)

Could anyone please guide me to proper call or API or Logic(in code and not on command line apart from directly killing the process) to handle this situation ?

Comment: You are (incorrectly) closing an accepted client socket, but are you also closing the listening server socket?  You cannot bind a new TCP socket to the same IP/port that a previous socket is still bound to.  Why are you trying to bind multiple sockets to the same IP/port in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
Yes i call close in both client and server socket.
The logic behind the same is my server thread is part of an application which is launched and based on successful launch i create the server thread.This thread need not unnecessarily be active even after my application is closed.To handle this condition i have tried to close the socket when my pthread_exit is called.
As far as client is concerned i assume its OK to call close when client is done with its work.
Please correct me wrong if my logic seems incorrect.

Comment: You are clearly not closing everything correctly. Something is still open. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing how you a managing all of the sockets.

Comment: Where is the code that is calling `close()` on `server_sockfd`? Where is the code that is calling `close()` on `client_sockfd`?  Again, please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing all *relevant* code related to your sockets.

Comment: @RemyLebeau
In Server
Main Server Thread
Infinite loop start
  In Server
Main Server Thread
Infinite loop start
  ret=recv(client_sockfd,&socket_read,4,0);
  if(ret == -1)
  {
   ALOGE("Socket:: Error recv Failed %s Retrying ..\n",strerror(errno));
   continue;
  }
  ALOGE("Socket:: Got socket_read %d\n",socket_read);
  if(socket_read == 2)
   //Condition is true so send notification
  if(Some break condition becomes true then break)
   break;
Closing part in server
  ret = close(client_sockfd);
  if(ret != 0)
   ALOGE("Socket:: Closed Called in FM %s\n",strerror(errno));
  client_sockfd = 0;

Comment: In client

Closing function

static void close_audio_socket()
{
 int ret=0;
 ret = close(socket_fd);
 if(ret != 0)
   ALOGV("Socket:: Closed Called %s\n",strerror(errno));
 socket_state = SOCKET_DISCONNECTED; //My state machine state
 sock_data = 0;
 ALOGV("Socket ::  Socket Connection Closed\n");
}

And this function is called everytime when we our application exits

So basically both Server and Client close are called everytime whic my app exits.

Comment: Please stop putting code in comments! [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34524763/edit) and put the code there instead, where it belongs.  And be sure to show where you are calling `close()` on your `server_sockfd` variable. I see `close(client_sockfd)` on the server, and `close(sockfd)` on the client, but where is `close(server_sockfd)` on the server?

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau
I think i got the problem.
I was closing the server socket fd which i got from accept() but was not closing server actual socket() fd
Now it seems to work.
Thanks for your information.
Will keep not of posting etiquette.

Answer (score 1):

> A socket is one half a channel of communication between two computers over a network on a particular port. (the other half is the corresponding socket on the other computer)

Error is very clear I suppose in this case. As mentioned `Address already in use`, so the the socket you are trying to connect in the second attempt is already used (port was already occupied) -> maybe due to first socket connection.

To investigate further check another [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352650/socket-address-already-in-use)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762859/how-to-avoid-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use)

Comment: Thanks.Indeed error is clear as i mentioned.But i want to re use the same port which i am unable to even after calling close (as well as shutdown()) before trying to reopen it.Above all close() doe snot return any error for the first time.If closing fails then close should throw error that the requested fd could not be closed.Hence my query.

Comment: @user5729621 Can you post the code snippet where you are closing previously opened socket?

Comment: I have already posted the same. What I mean is I tried with both shutdown Api and close Api but the next iterations of bind give error. Also I have tried with another port number but it throw same error

Comment: @user5729621 Hard to believe. If you used a different port number you should succeed, unless something else was already bound to that port. What IP:port are you trying to bind to?

Answer (score 0):

You can't share a TCP listening port between two processes even with SO_REUSEADDR.

NB `shutdown()` does not close a TCP session. It half-closes it. You have to close the socket.

Comment: The OP said: "*I tried with close as well but it did not work.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed. Hard to see why he bothered with `shutdown()` at all, and why he didn't use `close()` in the first place.